# Preparing iOS app for 5.0 and to be available on both iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am getting ready to submit my first iOS app to the app store and I have two questions. I have searched for the answers here and in the apple developer documentation. I'm sure I've missed it, so if someone can be point in the right direction I would be very appreciative.

1. I am using Xcode 4.2.1, so the deployment target is iOS 5.0. Will my app get rejected because it is not targeted for 6.0? Should I be using the latest version of Xcode?
2. The app was designed for the iPhone, but I would like it to be available on the iPad as well with the 2x magnification function. If I change the Targeted Device Family to iPhone/iPad, will I be able to submit it for purchase/download on both devices, or is there more I need to do to make it iPad compatible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

1. Your app will not get rejected for targeting a previous version of iOS. As a matter of fact, that's a good thing. The deployment target is just the minimum supported version of iOS, meaning that it will also be able to run on newer versions. I believe a lot of developers (including myself) choose to target iOS 5 to support a wider range of devices - as well as those people who are a bit slow to update their firmware.
2. All iPhone apps can be run in maginification mode on the iPad. You don't have to do anything special. As a matter of fact, you should not change your targeted device family as you do not really target the iPad but only the iPhone.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. Deployment target is the **minimum** supported version. You won't get rejected for what you put there.
2. If the targeted device family is iPhone, the 2x magnification function will be there for the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations on your first app!

For the first question, no, the deployment target only defines the minimum supported version for your app – for instance, if you have iOS 5.0 as the minimum, users with 5.0 and up (including 6.x) will be able to install the app and use it.

Secondly, you don't need to change the device target family for the magnification function to work on the iPad. In fact, by changing it to iPhone/iPad, it's recommended that you have two different "versions" of your app, one for iPhone and one for iPad.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to code anything to make your app work on the iPad. Your app will appear in the App Store as an iPhone / iPod Touch app, that iPad users will be able to download and use the 2x zoom.

I would advice you to submit the app and continue coding. This way you will continue coding and you will see if you app is rejected on no. If it is rejected, you will be able to change it before doing a big work.